# Windows 2008R2 IIS 7.5 refuses to load web.config

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

The message that I receive is "the requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid" (500.19, error code 0x80007000d).

After removing utf-8, or adding utf-16 to the xml root node in the web.config, IIS then serves pages. Where is the code page set for the site, as I've never run into this issue before?

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: It may not have anything to do with the problem, but does the `web.config` file have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) set? I can imagine that if the BOM conflicted with the XML root node `encoding` attribute, it could upset things.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, if you would be so kind as to answer the question, I'll mark it as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `web.config` file has a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) set, then the XML root node `encoding` attribute must match.